# JS Doc help. Document event listener

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Ive been learning how to use JSDoc with my projects, I mostly understand how  to use it with the exception of 1 or two things. One of these things being documenting event listeners.

Ive seen the documentation on the @listens, but the explanation/example they give is not making sense to me.

I was wondering if anyone has a better way of explaining it to me, or maybe show me an example of how you document a basic event listener. (Ill provide one below)

```js
document.getElementById('some_element').addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  // Some code
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSDoc documenting event listeners properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62576757/jsdoc-documenting-event-listeners-properly)