# JSDoc documenting event listeners properly

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Ive been learning how to use JSDoc with my projects, I mostly understand how  to use it with the exception of 1 or two things. One of these things being documenting event listeners.

Ive seen the documentation on the @listens, but the explanation/example they give is not making sense to me. Heres a link to the page: https://jsdoc.app/tags-listens.html

I was wondering if anyone has a better way of explaining it to me, or maybe show me an example of how you document a basic event listener. (Ill provide one below)

```js
document.getElementById('some_element').addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  // Some code
});
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by documenting event listeners? It seems that you are trying to ask how to write a Document listener instead.  Also, a link to the specific documentation that doesn't make sense to you could be helpful. Finally, more contextual code would be helpful for others as they would more easily pinpont the issue. Did you try that exemple line? If so, what kind of error or errors did you get in the console?

Comment: @rocha thanks for the comment. Ill edit my question to be more specific. Just to answer a couple of your questionsx my problem isnt with the code, im using a documenting tool called JSDoc, i want to know how to properly document listeners. Ill provide a link to the page in my question

Comment: Got it, thanks for the explanation. This specific line of code seems pretty straightforward to document even if the documention in JSDoc for the @events and @listens tags isn't helpfull at all, which is ironic. First, maybe a reference to the HTML element as a type: `@type {HTMLElement}`. Then something along these lines perhaps: `@event document#mousedown` or `@listens document#mousedown`, in which you declare the namespace first, followed by # and finally the event name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending on my comment above, I figure that the following would be an acceptable way to document that line of code, in which `document` is the namespace, followed by the event name `mousedown`:

```js
/**
 * Listen to mousedown event
 *
 * @type {HTMLElement} - the target of the event
 * @listens document#mousedown - the namespace and name of the event
 */

document.getElementById('some_element').addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  // Some code
});
```